# android 13 compilesdk 33 Pushnotifications onMessageReceived in FirebaseMessagingService not called on Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am updating my App to compileSDK 33.

The same App running on an Android 11 or 12 Device receives Pushnotifications without any problems. The Problem seems to especially be only with Android 13 devices.

(I dont get why Google annoyingly modifies its Code so that nothing works if you build for a newer SDK Level - Never had such problems with C++.)

The Firebaseversion is: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1'
CompileSdkVersion is 33 and TargetSDK is also 33

My FirebaseMessagingService looks like this:

```
public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static String strLogName = "XYZApp";

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Intent notificationIntent;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_EX = 7777;
    private FirebaseService m_instance;

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(strLogName, "onCreate() Firebase Service");
        m_instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(strLogName, "onMessageReceived(...)");
        try {
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(strLogName, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
                Log.d(strLogName, "Message Notification Tag: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag());
            }
            if (remoteMessage != null && remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                ...
                Log.d(strLogName,"Notification strMessage:"+strMessage);
                ...
            } else {
                Log.w(strLogName,"onMessageReceived without remoteMessage");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(strLogName,"Failed to receive Notification, Error:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

onCreate is called but (on sending a Pushnotification) not the onMessageReceived. But only on the Android 13 Device. There is no onMessageReceived(...) in the log and also no error Message.

I am asking for Notificationpermissons as it is now recommended:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 32) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("XYZApp", "Asking for Notification permissions");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                },7771);
            } else {
                Log.d("XYZApp", "Has already Notification permissions");
            }
        }
```

Which seems to work as I get the 'Has already Notification permission' on second start of the app.

I also added the POST_NOTIFICATION Permission in the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="4.0" android:versionCode="43" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="XYZ ABC" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:name="de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018.XYZApp" android:label="XYZ ABC" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:exported="true" android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPENXYZAPP"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            ...
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
            ...
        </activity>
        ...
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/noticon"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
        <service android:name="de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018.FirebaseService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
        </service>
        ...
    </application>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

I am creating a Notification Channel (which was also not needed in former SDK Versions):

```
public static String createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String channelId = "de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018.notification";
        CharSequence channelName = "XYZ ABC Deutschland";
        String channelDescription = "XYZ ABC Deutschland Nachrichten";
        int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        boolean channelEnableVibrate = true;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(channelEnableVibrate);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        Log.d(strLogName,"Firebase Channel created:"+channelName+" with ID:"+channelId);
        return channelId;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which I also can see in the log is created.

The default notification id is also correctly added to the App:

```
<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018.notification</string>
</resources>
```

As I wrote the same App works on Android 12 and Android 11 Devices w/o any problems.

The sended Notification Payload from my webservice looks like that:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "XYZ ABC 2023",
        "body": "Bla blu blub.",
        "click_action": "OPENXYZAPP",
        "sound": "default",
        "tag": "2303"
    },
    "data": {
        "base64": "ewkiaWQi"
    },
    "to": "/topics/debug2023",
    "content_available": true,
    "android": {
        "notification": {
            "click_action": "OPENXYZAPP",
            "channel_id": "de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018.notification",
            "android_channel_id": "de.einszweidrei.XYZ2018.notification"
        }
    }
}
```

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:replace="android:exported" />
```

android:exported="true" - should be true
also, you can use adb logcat to see all logs (not only for application)

Steps to solve this issue:

1. Check logs to understand if the message is received
2. Check firebase logs to check exceptions
3. If a message is received - then add logs to overridden FirebaseMessagingService methods

Answer (score -1):

If you are not requesting  POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission explicitly, then your app will not be able to receive push notifications on Android 13 devices.

To fix this issue, you need to add the following code to your app:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
}, 7771);
}
}
```

Comment: As stated in my question I had done this already.